# Проблема с областью видимости переменной

Tags: java

Добрый день.
Такой вопрос - внутри цикла **while** определяется значение переменной **n**, но за пределам цикла оно не доступно. Как можно его оттуда вытащить? Возможно ли как-то модифицировать область видимости для переменной?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    boolean j = false;
    int n;
    int[] arr1 = new int[n];
    while (!j){
        System.out.println("Введите четное положительное число");
        Scanner inc = new Scanner(System.in);
        n = inc.nextInt();
        if (n > 0 && n%2==0) j=true;
    }
    for (int i=0; i <=n; i++) {arr1[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 11 - 5);}
}}
```

Comment: `за пределам цикла оно не доступно` -- с чего Вы это взяли?

Comment: оно доступно и за пределами цикла. интересно зачем писать new int[n] когда n не определено?

Answer (score 3):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    boolean j = false;
    int n = 0;
    while (!j){
        System.out.println("Введите четное положительное число");
        Scanner inc = new Scanner(System.in);
        n = inc.nextInt();
        if (n > 0 && n%2==0) j=true;
    }
    int[] arr1 = new int[n];
    for (int i=0; i < n; i++) {arr1[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 11 - 5);}
}
```

Данная программа должна работать. Ошибка была в том, что с строке `int[] arr1 = new int[n];` использовалась переменная `n`, которая была определена на предыдущей строке, но не инициализирована. Инициализируется она лишь в цикле while в строке `n = inc.nextInt();`. Невозможно использовать то чего нет

Comment: "Должна работать", но не работает: ошибка в строке int[] arr1 = new int[n] и for (int i=0; i <=n; i++) т.к. переменная n не инициализирована, а переменная  n = inc.nextInt() доступна только в рамках цикла while

Comment: ´Невозможно использовать то чего нет´ Конечно возможно, без инициализации она даже скорее всего будет равна 0, или каким-то мусором, что ещё хуже. Но если она 0, то создаём нулевой массив, а потом в цикле обходишь его до n элементов... конечно оно не будет работать

Comment: @Sergey да, не обратил внимания на то, что в цикле for ты итерируешься от i=0 до i=n. Массив создается размера n, индексы у него от нуля до n-1 включительно, а цикл обращается к элементам массива от 0 до n включительно. Исправь `for (int i=0; i <=n; i++)` на `for (int i=0; i <n; i++)` и измени `int n;` на `int n = 0;`(тут компилятору не нравится что переменная с его точки зрения не всегда инициализируется, он думает что есть шанс не попасть в цикл while)

Comment: @Isaev, Без инициализации пример не скомпилируется.

Comment: @Isaev да, в конце предыдущего комментария уже написал это

Comment: @post_zeew ну я в яве не силён, во многих других языках скомпилировался бы молча. в любом случае логическую ошибку видно сразу

Comment: @Isaev если `n` - локальная переменная, то не скомпилируется. Если `n` - поле класса, то скопмилируется, и значение будет `0` (значение по умолчанию). Никакого мусора не будет. Значения по умолчанию указаны в [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5).

Answer (score 0):

Судя по всему, длина массива должна вводиться с клавиатуры и быть положительным четным числом, тогда массив должен создаваться внутри цикла и это может выглядеть так:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    boolean j = false;
    int n;
    while (!j) {
        System.out.println("Введите четное положительное число");
        Scanner inc = new Scanner(System.in);
        n = inc.nextInt();
        if (n > 0 && n % 2 == 0) {
            j = true;
            int[] arr1 = new int[n];
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                arr1[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 11 - 5);
            }
        } else
            System.out.println("Неверное число");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Сделать переменную статической, нет?

public class Main {

```
public static int n;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    boolean j = false;


    while (!j){
        n=0;
        System.out.println("Введите четное положительное число");
        Scanner inc = new Scanner(System.in);
        n = inc.nextInt();
        if (n > 0 && n%2==0) j=true;
    }
    int[] arr1 = new int[n];
    for (int i=0; i <n; i++) {arr1[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 11 - 5);}
}
```

}